# laravel pagination with LIKE in query string

Tags: php, laravel

I wanna paginate the result after filter data. So I use this script:

$companies = DB::table('user')->where('name', 'LIKE', $term)->paginate($per_page);

But it doesn't work and return the error as bellow:

```
Unhandled Exception
Message:

Undefined offset: 0

Location:

/var/www/myapps/laravel/view.php(354) : eval()'d code on line 13
```

Could u help me with this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeap I see the problem now,
It's actually not a problem in controller logic but view (The error message tempts me to check the controller for query database. e.g 'offset'). 
the offset here is the array offset return after controller query db.

just check the length of it and then it works ok

Comment: Your error already says its in the view. Just pay attention to error messages of what it is saying. It is there for a purpose.